# grouping every N number of elements

Tags: jquery

I have a ul which can have several li elements in it, I want every n number to be placed inside a div, so for example if this is the html:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
</ul>
```

I want the result to be something like this:

```
<div id=firstgroup">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</div>
<div id=secondgroup">
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</div>
<div id="thirdgroup">
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</div>
<div id=fourthgroup">
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
</div>
```

and so on, 
So here, we are grouping every 2 element into a new div.

Comment: your o/p html is invalid

Comment: Regardless of your reasoning.. you're doing it wrong. Just so very wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as below.

```
var li = $("ul li");
for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i+=2) {
  li.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div class='group'></div>");
}
```

#### [`Live Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/PwtpP/)

Answer (score 2):

Your output html is invalid, try something like below

```
var ids = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']

var li = $("ul li").unwrap();
for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i+=2) {
  li.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<ul id='" + ids[i/2] + "'></ul>");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PwtpP/1/)

Output

```
<ul id="first">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
<ul id="second">
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul id="third">
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
</ul>
<ul id="fourth">
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
</ul>
```